# Why am i getting a NullPointer?

Tags: android, video

i m trying to create a videoplayer that getting videos from a path in the sdcard.unfortunately i m getting a nullpointer!Could you please help me??
this is the code:

```
class VideoFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return (name.endsWith(".wmv"));
    }
}
public class video extends ListActivity {

    private static final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/videodata/");
    private List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> videoList ;
    File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
private VideoView mVideoView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {


           try {
                super.onCreate(icicle);
                setContentView(R.layout.main3);
                updateVideoList();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
            }


    }

    private void updateVideoList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        if (home.listFiles( new VideoFilter()).length > 0) {
            for (File file : home.listFiles( new VideoFilter())) {
                songs.add(file.getName());
            }
    videoList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.video_item,songs);

            setListAdapter(videoList);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {



        mVideoView.setVideoPath(MEDIA_PATH + songs.get(position));
        mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
    }

}
```

@martin if i do it like that

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);

        mVideoView.setVideoPath(MEDIA_PATH + songs.get(position));
        mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
    }
```

then i m getting `07-03 15:55:55.190: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4090): java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'`

EDIT:

```
public class mainscreen extends Activity {

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    final int VIDEOS = extras.getInt("VIDEO");  
    private VideoView mVideoView;

   String k= new Integer(VIDEOS).toString();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
        mVideoView.setVideoPath(k);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        mVideoView.requestFocus();

        }
```

thats the way i m passing the path string from the first activity t the second but its not working.............

Comment: the NullPointerException is here         mVideoView.setVideoPath(MEDIA_PATH + songs.get(position));

Comment: You don't appear to be initialising mVideoView anywhere, so it will be null.

Comment: i have updated my answer....why am i getting that error?

Comment: You subclassed a ListActivity, which requires you to have a ListView with the correct id in your layout... You might also consider using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to get the path to the sdcard rather than /sdcard/, as this could be different from one device to another.

Comment: hi can you please show us the main2.xml layout that you defined?

Answer (score 3):

You need to fetch your videoview first:

```
mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
```

**Edit**

Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'. It's as simple as that. In your main2.xml you need a ListView with the id 'list'.

**Edit2**

So you want to get rid of your ListView as you play the video. I'd recommend indeed starting a new Activity for this. ListActivity doesn't allow contents without a ListView.

Comment: i have tried it before but i m getting the runtimeexception i have wrote in my answer "edit"!

Comment: in my main3 layout i have 
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/sc"/>

Comment: You set your content to main2 just before using the listview. So do you have that as well in main2.xml?

Comment: no.in my main2 i only have a videoView...I would like when i press a list item to change the content view and have only a videoview..isnt that possible?

Comment: may i had to go in a new activity with a videoView only?

Comment: No, because you're using ListActivity. If you just use Activity, then it would work.

Comment: So i have to use putExtra and pass my path to a new activity?